# Wall/Line Following Operation

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to implement a wall/line following protocol on my robot, and I'm not sure how to go about doing so. To make things more difficult, the robot must follow a wall that's not always in the same place (so I cannot use it for localization with amcl), there's no `a priori` knowledge of the length of the wall, the wall is not guaranteed to be a continuous straight, and the path must be smooth (no pauses between waypoint assignments) because the robot travels at up to 15mph.

Because of these factors, I don't think that I can use the navigation stack. I was just wondering if anyone else has encountered a similar problem and if you found a solution. Perhaps there is an alternative navigation stack somewhere, or there is a specific planner I could use for this purpose?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: My sensor array includes, but is not limited to: two single-line laser scanners, a four-line laser scanner, IMU, GPS (outdoor robot), PTZ camera, etc.

Currently, the two single-line scanners are configured to be co-planar, such that they can detect obstacles in a 360 degree arc around the robot. The four-line scanner faces downward to profile the ground in front of the robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12574/wall/line-following-operation/) by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-10**:
What sort of sensors do you have available? This sounds like something I did freshman year with a microcontroller, a distance sensor and a PID loop.

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-03-15**:
Hello, could you figure out the way to do what you asked. i have a Turtlebot with URG lidar, looking to do the same wall following thing, but im stuck. if you had a success do you mind sharing the method u used? thnX!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
What about creating a virtual goto point in front of the robot and at a certain distance from the wall? Then implementing a simple follower to reach that point, that is always being pushed forward.
Or as suggested by @ahendrix, just implementing a simple control loop to maintain a distance from the wall sending direct velocity commands to your base.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0